# How to put update/insert in same php file as search

Tags: php, mysql, sql-update, sql-insert

So I have this "Result" page in which you have input fields,and there is dropdown menu to choose Tournament name and submit it and it works like search,when you choose and press submit it fills inputs with names from database.And now I need to enable update or insert on empty fields in the same php file.Here is php for for "search" button.Please tell me how and where to enable input/update query for empty fields.

```
<?php $conn = new mysqli('host', 'user', 'pass', 'db')  or die ('Cannot connect to db');
$result = $conn->query("select team1,team2 from tournament where tname LIKE '%".$_POST['tname']."%'    ");
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
      unset($team1);
      $team1 = $row['team1']; 
      echo '<input style="margin:54px 0px 0px 8px;width:139px;height:27px"; value="'.$team1.'"/>';
      unset($team2);
      $team2 = $row['team2']; 
      echo '<input style="margin:0px 0px 0px 925px;width:139px;height:27px"; value="'.$team2.'"/>';
}; ?>
```

Code for getting dropdown.

```
$result = $conn->query("select tname from tournament ");
echo "<select name='tname'>";
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
       unset($tname);
       $tname = $row['tname']; 
       echo '<option value="'.$tname.'">'.$tname.'</option>'; 
}
echo "</select>";
$tname=$_POST[tname]; ?>
```

Comment: And adding a couple of lines to perform the `insert` / `update` after the code you've already got doesn't work because...?

Comment: form submit with `ISSET()` coming in and `if` statements to know what mode you are in. A cryptic answer, but heh

Comment: It doesn't work,because there is only one button submit and before pressing it everything is empty,and I must press it to get values from db.Tried to press it few times when values come but nothing happens in db.

Comment: I think that ISSET() will work,gonna try it,thanks :)

Comment: I don't really know to use ISSET(),done it like this but doesn't work :/   if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
 $sql="insert into tournament(team1,team2) values('".$_REQUEST['team1']."','".$_REQUEST['team2'])."') where tname LIKE '%".$_POST['tname']."%' "; 
 $res=mysql_query($sql); 
}